# mysql count which record it is in ordered mode?

Tags: mysql

Consider this table

```
id  -  name  -  age
 1    jonny      12
 2    al         16
 3    lory       22
```

Now ordering for age we have Lory, Al, Jonny.

Is there a fast way to select which number jonny is in the list ?

Considering this order `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY age DESC`, jonny is 3rd.

Something like: `SELECT *, * rank(age) as position** FROM table WHERE id = 1`

EDIT:

I can count the records that have the age > my record: so the query become:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE age > (SELECT age FROM table WHERE id = 1) as t1
```

I have accepted an answer but i rly don't like to use vars in sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @name = 'al';
select @name,count(*) + 1 as rank from 
    (select * from `table` where age > 
       (select age from `table` where name=@name) order by age desc)as tab;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 rownum
FROM
    (
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, id,age,name
    FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) table
    ORDER by age desc
    ) temp
WHERE
    temp.name = 'jonny'
```